# Is it possible in C# to return a array back to the calling program?

Tags: c#

Is it possible in C# to return a array back to the calling program? If it is not possible, please say it is not all possible. Another alternative is to create a long string and use string.split(). But that does not look nice.
ExamnationOfReturnsFiled("ABCDE1234E") //Calling program.

```
public  yearsfiled[] ExamnationOfReturnsFiled(string panreceived) //function.
{            
    int k = 0; //to increment the array element.
    string item = panreceived; //string value received call program.

    string[] yearsfiled = new string[20];//Declaring a string array.
    Regex year = new Regex(@"[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}");//to capture 2012-13 like entries.
    using (StreamReader Reader1 = new StreamReader(@"C: \Users\Unnikrishnan C\Documents\Combined_Blue_Book.txt"))
    {
        Regex tofindpan = new Regex(item);//Regular Expression to catch the string from the text file being read.
        bool tosearch = false;
        Regex blank = new Regex(@"^\s*$"); //to detect a blank line.
        while ((str.line1 = Reader1.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            Match Tofindpan = tofindpan.Match(@"[A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}");
            Match Blank = blank.Match(line1);
            if (Blank.Success)
            {
                tosearch = false;
            }
            if (Tofindpan.Success)
            {
               tosearch = true; //when true the 
            }
            if (tosearch == true)
            {
               Match Year = year.Match(str.line1);
               if (Year.Success)
               {
                   yearsfiled[k] = Year.Value;
                   k++;
               }
            }
        }
        return yearsfiled;
    }
```

}

Comment: If you move your _return yearsfiled_ outside the while loop probably you have better chances to get something out of this code.

Comment: the return should be moved outside. That was a mistake on my part. Done. Thanks

Comment: Of course it is possible to return an array. However you should revise your code thoroughly for its logic. What is the role of the panreceived for example, or checking nonblank lines.

Comment: My problem is now solved. However I wish to answer the points raised by Cetin Basoz. The programme reads each line to find out something in the regex format of [A-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{1}. But I need to capture not all but only certain predetermined entries matching the regex. Then the capturing process begings the bool value becomes 'true'. It has to stop once there is a blank line because whatever lies between the regex and the blank line only I need to get to process further. Thank you @Cetin Basoz.

Comment: I see but your code is not working like that. It wouldn't stop on blank line after finding a match.

Comment: It is supposed to stop the search temporarily and then proceed next to find another. The blank line is a break. After that it goes on search but will not write the contents to the text file in between the matches. It is working and I am satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`public  string[] ExamnationOfReturnsFiled(string panreceived)` //function

you are returning type not variable name change the method signature like above

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning a `string[]`. Your return type `yearsfiled[]` is a variable name, not a type name

Answer (score 0):

//from calling programme. Tested and succeeded.

```
string[] yearsfiled = new string[20];
yearsfiled = ExamnationOfReturnsFiled(item1);
```

// the function name modified as follows.

```
public static string[] ExamnationOfReturnsFiled(string panreceived)
{
  Everything else as in the original post.
}
```

//It was tested. And found successful. Thanks so much to @Midhun Mundayadan and @Eavidan.